# Instance Method returning the wrong value

Tags: python, class, instance, renpy

I have a class for a Dialogue system as follows

```
class DIALOGUE(object):
    def __init__(self, place, who, sTime, eTime, isActive, mood, menuText, func, repeatable, num):
        self.place = place
        self.who = who
        self.sTime = sTime
        self.eTime = eTime
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.mood = mood
        self.menuText = menuText
        self.func = func
        self.repeatable = repeatable
        self.num = num

    @property
    def ACheck(self):
        global Date
        if self.sTime == "none":
            return True
        else:
            tHour,tMin = self.sTime.split(":")
            if tHour >= Date.Hour and tMin <= Date.Minute:
                tHour,tMin = self.eTime.split(":")
                if tHour < Date.Hour and tMin < Date.Minute:
                    return True
        return False

    @property
    def BCheck(self):
        global Act
        if self.who == Act:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @property
    def CCheck(self):
        global Location
        if self.place == Location:
            return True
        if self.place == "none":
            return True
        return False

    @property
    def DCheck(self):
        if self.repeatable:
            return True
        else:
            if self.num > 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True

    @property
    def CanChat(self):
        if self.isActive and self.ACheck and self.BCheck and self.CCheck and self.DCheck:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def SetActive(self):
        self.isActive = True

    def Do(self):
        self.num += 1
        renpy.call(self.func)
```

Most of this should be self explanatory but I parse an XML file into a list of Instances of this class.

The user is presented with a list of available dialogues based on what Location they are in, what time of day it is and what NPC they have selected. If the dialogue is not repeatable The DCheck method looks at whether or not the dialogue has been completed before i.e if the dialogue is not repeatable and `self.num > 0` the method will return `False`

Essentially it loops through all the dialogues and carries out `i.CanChat` and if this value returns True, the Dialogue is added to the menu

The issue I'm having is that the Check methods aren't returning the correct value. Specifically DCheck is returning True all the time, regardless of whether the Dialogue is repeatable or not, and ignoring the value of `self.num`

The class is created in an `init python:` block and then the xml file is parsed in a separate python block which is called from inside the start label

It's probably something really simple but I can't figure it out.

The list of instances is parsed as follows

```
Dialogues = []
    for j in Dialo:
        JPlace = j.find('Place').text
        JWho = j.find('Who').text
        JsTime = j.find('Start').text
        JeTime = j.find('End').text
        JMood = int(j.find('Mood').text)
        JText = j.find('Text').text
        JFunc = j.find('Func').text
        JRep = j.find('Rep').text
        if JRep == "True":
            Jrep = True
        else:
            Jrep = False
        Dialogues.append(DIALOGUE(JPlace, JWho, JsTime, JeTime, False, JMood, JText, JFunc, JRep, 0))
```

The method for creating the menu is as follows

```
def TalkCheck():
    talks = []
    talks.append(("Nevermind.", "none"))
    for i, q in enumerate(Dialogues):
        if q.CanChat:
            talks.append((q.menuText,i))
    renpy.say(None, "", interact=False)
    talkchoice = renpy.display_menu(talks)
    if talkchoice <> "none":
        talkchoice = int(talkchoice)
        Dialogues[talkchoice].Do()
```

Comment: `DCheck()` quite certainly does take `self.num` into account; the problem is more likely in the code or data that originally set that value.  And are you even sure that's where the problem is coming from?  (I ask because the time comparison logic in `ACheck()` is broken, you should only be comparing the minutes if the hours were equal.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ive added the code which parses the xml file into the list to the bottom of the question if it helps

Comment: I don't spot any obvious error with the parsing code either - at least the types for `repeatable` and `num` seems correct. No way to help without inspecting the effective values (at the moment the function is called). Please post a proper MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete - you didn't post a MCVE, we don't know the effective values for "repeatble" and "num" that leads to this behaviour, and we don't even know if it's using Python 2.x or Python 3.x - so we can just try and guess.  Now since you mention that you "parse an XML file into a list of instances", I stronly suspect you are running Python 2.x and passing those values as strings instead of (resp.) boolean and int. In Python 2, `"-1"` (string) compares greater than `0` (int) - it raises a `TypeError` in Python 3.x -, and in both cases a non-empty string evals to `True` in a boolean context (`bool('False') == True`). Since there's no obvious logical error in your method implementation, that's the only explanation I can think of.

BTW, expressions have a boolean values and `return` exits the function, so you can simplify your code:

```
@property
def DCheck(self):
    if self.repeatable:
        return True
    return self.num > 0
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the reply. I've added the parsing code to the question. Renpy uses Python 2.x so that would be a correct assumption

Comment: Well I see nothing wrong with the parsing code, so we're back to guessing games.